# IntelliJ import project

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, import

When I try to import project from the source ode of one of books I read and try to start it an error occur which saying: `Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Catalina:type=Server`. It uses Tomcat and I think that the problem is in configurations.
Has anyone some idea why is that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of things you should take consideration. I will try to exemplify the import of a project which uses apache tomcat as server.

- Download and install Apache Tomcat
- Configure PATH for Tomcat
- Put all Libraries which you want to deploy in you /lib/ folder at Tomcat folder's
- Import in IntelliJ
- F4 for project properties. Go to artifacts and configure a new Web Application

  - IntelliJ menu go to Run -> Edit Configurations
  - Create and configure a new tomcat server
  - put your web application as artifact for deploy

Voilà